# Blurred, embedded raster image after importing PDF in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, image-editing, blur, raster, embed

I imported a figure from PDF (generated from Latex) into Inkscape as SVG for final editing. It contains a raster image, which for some reason is completely blurred and I cannot figure out why. Any ideas?

Note that the format of the image was not maintained also (perhaps this helps). I made a separate question for that here: [Cannot change aspect ratio of embedded raster image after PDF import](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116771/cannot-change-aspect-ratio-of-embedded-raster-image-after-pdf-import)

Here is the image:
[image: Blurred raster image after PDF import]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a low resolution image, that might explain the blurring. Without seeing the SVG, I can't be 100% sure but you could try this:

- Select the raster image
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open the
  Object Properties panel.
- In the Object Properties set the Image Rendering to '*optimizeSpeed*'

Obviously the image will be blocky/pixelated, but that is because it is low resolution.  Nothing you can really do about that except output a higher quality (larger) raster image.